# How to render a very complex scene using Render Layers?

Tags: render-layers

So that the Alpha Over property is implicitly applied to every frame after I do it on the first frame.

*I am using Cycles Render, and Blender 2.75*

**Edit** - The full image has soldiers and the plane. One image has the plane and one image as only the soldiers.

The soldiers are animated, but are in a different layer than the plane. I want them to be rendered with the animation along with the plane without moving them to the same layer (using Render Layers.)

P.S. The soldier count will increase greatly later.

This is the soldier layer - [image]

This is the plane layer- [image]

This is the full one (both soldiers and plane) - [image]

Comment: Do you mean you want to composite your render layers together with a simple alpha over and then render out the combined frame?

Comment: @ToddMcIntosh Yes, exactly!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more information,  add images of your current setup. How many layers do you have what are the contents of them and what is the desired effect you are after.

Comment: @cegaton I have edited the question. Please see.

Comment: I'm assuming you will want shadows from the soldiers to fall on the ground? If you really don't want to render the soldier and ground at once (ie for memory reasons), you might have to add another shadow catcher plane and composite in the shadows.

Comment: The answer to how to comp the 2 layers together is very easy, but I think we're trying to figure out why you need to do it this way. Why can't you render the soldier and ground in one layer. Are you trying to reduce memory usage by splitting them out?

Comment: @ToddMcIntosh Yes, I want to reduce memory usage.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I'm going to get the ball rolling by answering your question at face value. Here's a simple alpha over composite with 2 Render Layers.

I have 2 Scene Layers active, and have assigned each scene layer to a render layer. You'll notice that the shadow is rendered on the ground layer. This is because both layers go into memory and the monkey casts a shadow on the ground even though the monkey is not rendered in  layer one. If (for memory reasons) you did not want the monkey to affect the render calculations for Render Layer 1, you would add an Exclude selection for layer 2 on the Ground Render Layer. If you did this it might help with the rendering load, but you would lose your shadow on the ground, and would have to render it another way. If your ground object was really complicated and heavy (rendering wise), you could add a second simple plane on a third layer that could be used to generate the shadows for your solider layer, and the composite the 3 layers together.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! If I hit animation button (beside render button), will this setup remain the same for all frames or I will have to setup this node setup for every frame?

Comment: It stays the same for each frame. You'll also need to make sure you have Transparent checked in the Render>Film panel.