# Best way to create Godzilla's Atomic Breath (Cycles)?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles, physics

I've been trying to find tutorials out there that at least have a similar result to what I'm looking for, but I've failed to find anything close enough. I have some experience with particles and cycles, but not enough to find a way to do this on my own. I'm trying to replicate [this specific variant](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=btTsrk8DY2M).
[image]

What would be the best way to recreate this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

*UPDATE- I managed to make this using volumetric scattering and emission. It's close to what I'm looking for, but I need to make it flow in a specific direction, similar to what is shown in the video I linked. I've attempted using particles and smoke (smoke was a massive headache for me), but haven't gotten any successful results. This is for a film project I plan on working in the future, and is going to be used as VFX rather than a still image.
[image: AtomBreath]

*FINAL UPDATE- I've finally found a result that satisfied me. I abandoned the 2001 style atomic breath and went with the 2002-2004 breath. What I did was create a cylinder, make it have a short shape key, and a long shape key, and use quick smoke. I make the cylinder share a material with the smoke domain to make it "invisible" in the render (could create a new material but I was just lazy.) I used the fire sim, and In the node editor, set the flame emission like so.
[image: FlameNodeSetup]
Almost done. To make the the breath flow, I created a wind force, running prefectly along with the cylinder, and parented it to it. Adjust the strength to your desire. Finally, I set the flame to dissolve over time. The dissolve time depends on the length of the cylinder, so there's no set number. There is likely a much better for the flowing movement, but I am still very new to blender, and it works for now. Thank you for the tips and suggestions, I will centainly use them for future work. Here's the [final resul](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2IvgKniZcHo)t.
[image: AtomBreath]

Comment: See if these help http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53032/how-do-you-use-blender-to-make-pokemon-attacks-like-hyper-beam-and-solar-beam

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48816/how-to-create-a-fire-light-effect-in-a-spaceship-engine

Comment: Those are great tutorials, but not so much the result I'm looking for. I appreciate the suggestions though, thank you.

Comment: @MrGodzilla445 You should post your solution as an answer, it's fantastic!

Answer (score 6):

One of the method may be using some ***Blur (Fast Gausian)*** nodes in the ***compositor***.
[image]

First check the ***Transparent*** checkbox in the *Film* panel of the *Render* header.
[image]

Add a *cylinder*, subdivide and shape it. Give it the *Emission* shader. Render image (<kbd>F12</kbd>). Go to *compositor* and add some ***Blur (Fast Gaussian)*** nodes with the different bluring values. Use *Alpha Over* nodes to mix them. Use *Color* node to color the beam as you like (in my case I used it to color the glow blue).

Use ***Render Layers*** ([How to render a very complex scene using Render Layers?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56236/how-to-render-a-very-complex-scene-using-render-layers)) to add a background or your scene with Godzilla in it to the final render.
[image: ![enter image description here]

---

***EDIT:*** You can add two cylinders and place them in two different render layers. Each cylinder may have its own deforming shapekeys to affect the beam transformations. You may then parent both cylinders to the deforming bones. Here's the animated result. I know it isn't exactly the same as in the movie you provided but I guess it's a good start for experiments.
[image]

Comment: Thank you. It's a great start, but I should have clarified it in the OP, It's not for a still. It's for a film I'll be working on, and I need it to be a physical presence in the world. I'd do the actual breath in after effects, but it tends to look less tangible than something rendered in world.

Comment: Please check out my edit. It may be animated. I've uploaded the test animated gif. Using the proper techniqes (*Vawe Modifier* maybe) it may look the same as in the movie clip you provided.

Comment: I think, it would look much better with so me randomnes in the emmision. You could use cloud texture as factor or something like that.

Comment: Sorry for replying so late. For a couple days now, Chrome has refused to load Stack Exchange, but It's working now. In that time, I did however find a satisfactory result. I'll still use the tips you gave for future work though. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @MrGodzilla445 If you found the proper solution, could you share it with us and post your own answer explaining how to do it? It'll be helpful for the people looking for it in the future.

Comment: @PaulGonet Added the steps in the OP.