# Creating static condensation trails in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I am making a scene of a few F/A-18s launching off of an aircraft carrier, and I was wondering how I would set some condensation/vapor trails from the wing tips of the jets. I am only making a static scene, not an animation. I'm on Blender 2.73. If anyone can show me how I would do this, I would be very grateful.

edit: image for clarification on vapor trails
[image]
I would like to make the same effect as you see in the image

Comment: try volumetric shaders

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48816/how-to-create-a-fire-light-effect-in-a-spaceship-engine and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65899/best-way-to-create-godzillas-atomic-breath-cycles

Comment: Maybe related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45328/trail-particles-ending-in-a-point